# How to remove vertical dotted line in Victory Charts

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

I'm using Victory Chart in React Native. Everything works fine but can't remove/hide the vertical dotted line as you see in the given picture. How can I remove this `y-axis` vertical dotted line? Here is my code

```
<VictoryChart
  theme={VictoryTheme.material}
  animate={{
    duration: 2000,
    onLoad: { duration: 1000 },
  }}
>
  <VictoryPie
    colorScale={['#008FFB', '#82C9FF']}
    data={graphData}
    innerRadius={60}
    labels={[]}
  />

  {/*--- some code for Victory Label ---*/}

  <VictoryAxis
    style={{
      axis: { stroke: 'none' },
      ticks: { stroke: 'none' },
      tickLabels: { fill: 'none' },
    }}
    standalone={false}
  />
</VictoryChart>
```

[image: victory pie chart example]

Answer (score 3):

Just found the answer from the doc, so I'm writing here. Hope anyone will be helped.

Add the `grid` property in the VictoryAxis's style and set the `stroke` transparent.

```
<VictoryAxis
  style={{
    axis: { stroke: 'none' },
    ticks: { stroke: 'none' },
    tickLabels: { fill: 'none' },
    grid: { stroke: 'transparent' }
  }}
  standalone={false}
/>
```

[Official Documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis#style)